# Uncaught Type Error for creating an empty div in JS

Tags: javascript, typeerror, createelement

So what I have is a script to generate snowflakes and everything was working fine. I'm going for raw javascript here. No jquery whatsoever. So I want to just throw the script in and it creates its own classes and assigns them without a previously made style-sheet. So I create the element and then try to append it to the body, but it says the element is null.

...

```
<script>
  this.elem = document.createElement('div');
  document.getElementById('body').appendChild(this.elem);                           //appending flake to body
</script>
```

...

this gives an error.

Comment: Do you have an element with id "body"?

Comment: no but i didn't put a hashtag so isn't that correct reference to the body? It was working before when i had jquery selectors but now i cant seem to select the created element or reference it. this.elem apparently returns a div object that can't be appended

Comment: No, "#" is required in jQuery for selecting an element with a specific id. But javascript does not follow this syntax. When you say document.getElementById('body'), it means it will select an element with and id 'body'. That's the reason your code gives an error because it's not able to find the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use getElementsByTagName:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(this.elem);
```

if you're trying to append inside `<body></body>`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by changing your `HTML` markup to this;

```
<body id="body">
</body>
```

Same code will work fine.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/3jj02dau/)**

If you don't want to change `HTML` markup you can achieve it by `getElementsByTagName` as answered by @Bhojendra